# Xquery to return rows with restricted nodes

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

I have a table where a column contains XML data. Now i want to retrieve those xml data with restriction of nodes. Kindly see the following example for more explanation on my scenario,

```
declare @table table (id int, xmlfield xml) insert into @table select 1,'<Root xmlns="">
    <Sample>
    <Issue>
      <Level>one</Level>
      <Descp>First Example</Descp>
    </Issue>
    <Issue>
      <Level>two</Level>
      <Descp>Second Example</Descp>
    </Issue>
    </Sample> </Root>'

      select * from @table
```

Now i need the following result set

```
Id  XMLfield

1   first example
```

ie, for the selected level,i need the decription for it. More clearly,  the node should be restricted for `<level>one</level>`

(need: What is the description for level one ?)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)

```
select id,
       xmlfield.value('(//Issue[Level = "one"]/Descp/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as XMLField
from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

The XQuery you're looking for is

```
//Issue[Level = "one"]/Descp/data()
```

Comment: Can you please give me the full query ? and i dont understand what this query is going to do. I am completely new to xqueries